# VNC server on Ubuntu 12.04 is not working -- external VNC clients cannot access

Tags: 12.04, remote-desktop, vnc

I did:

```
sudo apt-get install vnc4server
```

then:

```
vncserver
```

But VNC viewer at a Windows computer could not access the Ubuntu.

Then, I did:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-core
```

But still no access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu already has a VNC server called `vino`. Vino is pre-installed.

If you run

```
vino-preferences
```

you will get a dialog box to help you configure the VNC server, and even make your computer accessible for VNC from the Internet (if you wish to).

I recommend removing the packages you installed and use vino.

In addition, the pre-installed VNC client for Ubuntu is `remmina`.

Comment: Thanks, will do.
How do I safely remove (uninstall) vnc4server and gnome-core?

Comment: You can remove them with `sudo apt-get remove ....`. Since you installed them, they should also uninstall as well.

Comment: vino works great.  Just one problem: I have to log in physically at the Linux Ubuntu computer before I remote into it from another computer, otherwise the VNC fails.  Any solution?